# What software is out there for domain availability in bulk for free?

Tags: dns, whois, domainservices

I am looking for software (possibly a website) where I can check domains in bulk for availability - and a very large number of them ~ 500 000 including tlds such as .in, .it, .nl and other 2 letter domains (not just .com, .net, .org etc). Does anyone know of anything suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use BulkRegister when I did this a few years ago.
I'm afraid I can't access the website from here to try it, so it may not be available any more!